# Passphrase failed

Tags: encryption, passphrase

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 but few weeks ago, it didn't accept my passphrase. I am sure I am putting it right. It contains special characters ))((
I tried to use live USB and the volume is shown as encrypted and again doesn't access the passphrase.
Is there a way to solve this or to change the passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

If your passphrase contains the numbers and you use num-keypad to enter the numbers - be sure the NUMLOCK is on. I know it's stupid, but once I got 3-minutes troubleshooting job done to figure out that my disk is not accepting the passphrase just because of it....

Comment: Many thanks Zoubak. I have tried this but still not accepting the password. Anything else I can do?

Comment: It seems that problem is serious. Sometime it happens the crypt header is corrupted (ex.: power failure). If you used luks encryption - the only remedy is to restore headers from previously saved back-up (if you fortunately did it) - just run sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore /dev/sdXn --header-backup-file /path/your_header_backup_file. For ecryptfs system the procedure is different. Please let me know what encryption you used.